# Almacenar varchar en mayusculas desde la tabla Postgress

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

me gustaria saber si es posible almacenar el texto de una columna tipo varchar en mayusculas, aunque el usuario interte el valor en minusculas. Seria a traves de la tabla, sin vistas ni reglas insert, update ni delete.

Pense en algo asi:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pro.proyecto (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
upper(cod) VARCHAR(14) as codigo
);
```

Pero da erro de sintaxis. He probado a hacer el upper en un insert de prueba y si que lo hace, pero en este caso me interesaria que la propia tabla lo guardara en mayusculas directamente, sin hacer funciones ni triggers.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obligar a escribir la columna en mayúscula, podrías hacer uso de la restricción [**`CHECK`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html), por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pro.proyecto (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    cod VARCHAR(14) CHECK (upper(cod) = cod)
);
```

Si por el contrario quieres permitir que se escriba de cualquier modo y convertirlo a mayúscula internamente, puedes crear un `TRIGGER`, por ejemplo:

```
-- Función que es invocada desde el TRIGGER
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uppercase_cod_on_insert() RETURNS trigger AS $uppercase_cod_on_insert$
    BEGIN        
        NEW.cod = UPPER(NEW.cod);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$uppercase_cod_on_insert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Trigger

CREATE TRIGGER uppercase_cod_on_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON pro.proyecto
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE uppercase_cod_on_insert();
```

- Fuente: [*Create a Postgres rule or trigger to automatically convert a column to lowercase or uppercase on insert*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939742/5587982) (`stackoverflow` en inglés)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con eso conseguiría que me diera error a la hora de insertarlo, pero obligo al usuario a ponerlo en Mayúsculas. 

Mi idea era, que se guardara directamente en mayúsculas, aunque el usuario lo introduzca en minúsculas.

Un saludo

Comment: @user3158502 entiendo. En ese caso puedes programar entonces un `TRIGGER`, para que reciba el dato como el usuario lo escriba y haga la conversión antes de insertarlo.

Comment: Me da que va a ser la única forma de hacerlo... pensaba que desde la tabla se podría. Gracias :)

Comment: @user3158502 he agregado un ejemplo de la función y el `TRIGGER` que podrías implementar.

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano :)